# How to use nuxtjs and axios?

Tags: axios, nuxtjs

I am trying to learn NuxtJs, I have been following documentation but i am having problems while using `$axios` or `this.$axios`. I try to create a services directory to make my requests to my api to make things organized and clean. First I have configured my nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios)
  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/"
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/'
    }
  },
```

and then I have created my `store` file `articles.js`

```
import articlesService from '~/services/articlesService'
export const state = () => ({
    indexArticles: [],
})
export const actions = {
  async fetchArticles ({ commit, dispatch }) {
    try {
      const response = await articlesService.fetchArticles()
      commit('fetchStart')
      commit('setArticles', response.data.results)
      commit('fetchEnd')
      this._vm.$q.loading.hide()
      return response
    } catch (error) {
      commit('setError', error)
      this._vm.$q.loading.hide()
    }
  },
}
```

and `articlesServices.js` file:

```
function fetchIndexArticles () {
  return this.$axios.get('articleslist/index/')
}
export default {
  fetchIndexArticles
}
```

I have tried variations:

```
function fetchIndexArticles ({$axios}) {
  return $axios.get('articleslist/index/')
}
```

Only working one is but all my requests will be such similar and hard-coded:

```
import axios from 'axios'
function fetchIndexArticles () {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/articleslist/index/')
}
```

Can you show me the correct usage of `axios` of `NuxtJs` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to using $

```
function fetchIndexArticles () {
  return this.$axios.$get('articleslist/index/')
}
```

Comment: I tried that but result is same, no server request, I have custom folder services. is it related to that ?